# File Glob in C++

Tags: c++, perl, file, glob

What's the C++ way of Perl's idiom:

```
my @files = glob("file*.txt");
foreach my $file (@files) {

   # process $file
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no standard C++ way to emulate this because there is no standard C++ functionality of reading the contents of a directory. What you can do is use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm):

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp> // plus iostream,algorithm,string,iterator
using namespace boost::filesystem; // and std

struct pathname_of {
    string operator()(const directory_entry& p) const {
        return p.path().filename(); // or your creativity here
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    transform(directory_iterator("."), directory_iterator(),
              ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"),
              pathname_of());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there ANYTHING boost can't do?!?!

Comment: @Wilhelm: Thanks. How do you compile that? I tried this but failed `g++ -I ~/.boost/include/boost-1_38 wiltell_code.cpp -o wiltell_code`

Comment: What error do you get? Compiler, linker? Make sure you add the missing include: `<algorithm>`. Say `std::for_each()` or add a `using` statement. Are you on Linux or Mac? If you're on Linux make sure you link against `boost_filesystem`. With g++ you can say `-lboost_filesystem`. If you're on a Mac you probably also need to link against `boost_system`.

Comment: I updated the example to something more useful, something that would give some output. Also I added in comment the code you must add for the thing to compile. Remember to add `-lboost_filesystem` (and `-lboost_system` if you're on a Mac like yours truly) when you run g++. When you run the executable you should get a listing of the files and directory under the current directory.

Comment: How does this code process only files that match the glob "file*.txt"?

Comment: It doesn't; it processes all files. I was just illustrating how to traverse a filesystem. If you want to filter out certain files then you can use a (non-standard) `copy_if()` algorithm rather than `transform()`. You then provide the algorithm a predicate which decides whether to process a given filename or not. You can use Boost.Regex for the predicate, and that would give you much more power than globbing. I don't think Boost has a glob function, but you can use the POSIX `fnmatch()`, or Windows' `PathMatchSpecEx()`.

Comment: If you're going to do that a lot then you might write a `filtered_directory_iterator` to extend Boost's filesystem library. This would make the calling code somewhat less cryptic.

Answer (score 18):

The POSIX API specifies the `glob()` and `globfree()` functions for this. See the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man3/glob.3.html). `wordexp()` and `wordfree()`, also specified by POSIX, support [other kinds of expansions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man3/wordexp.3.html) as well.

Comment: Hah, no kidding... It does.  Thanks for posting that!

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic the "glob" using `fnmatch`.  But you'll need to open the directory, read the contents, and match each entry using `fnmatch`.

No direct equivalent that's standard AFAIK.

Answer (score -2):

Call me old school.

```
f = popen("ls file*.txt", "r");
```

Comment: I call it unnecessary... uses `fork()` and `exec()` along with a bunch of others all for something that should take only one system call

Comment: Just a nit to diamotte's comment, glob() most certainly does more than one system call. It does dynamic memory allocation inside of the pglob structure you provide, and it has to read in the directory, so that's at least two syscalls.

But it is just one library call, and that is preferred. And given Wayne's solution will cause a shell to be spawned which will in turn call glob() or similar, it's clear that the glob() solution is strictly better.

Comment: Ick. That's not "old school", it's just plain horrible. -1.